# can't run git on jenkins, error code 13, permission denied

Tags: git, jenkins, permission-denied

I am using git to pull code from bitbucket, we can run git commands from jenkins master(Ubuntu 18.04 VM) server directly:

[image: simple git command]

But we can't run the same command from jenkins console:

[image]

Stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:621)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:451)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProcessGroovyMethods.execute(ProcessGroovyMethods.java:533)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$895.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
```

Need help about how to solve this issue.

Comment: after access to jenkins server, did you switch to jenkins user `su - jenkins`?

Comment: I can run git command after I changed the user to jenkins: `jenkins@frmp-jenkins-vm:/home/admin$ git
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan ^^

Comment: on my jenkins server, it works fine `Result

usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]`

Comment: On the jenkins server, all the commands can runs well, but I can't run the git commands on jenkins console, neither on the jenkins job, that's the weird thing. @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: Could you run this command from Jenkins console and send the response please? 
`println "which git".execute().text`

Comment: @Tolqiu It works fine, the result is `/usr/bin/git`

Comment: Access to jenkins server and run: chmod 777 /usr/bin/git

Answer (score 0):

There could be different problems, try to run the git in shell command in this runner or check the user name/id of running environment (does have this user assigned a shell in system profile?) i.e. you can run the git in that console with full path (if this work then you console is without assigned shell (bash/zsh etc. .e. no PATH and others environment variables)